# How to use BindingContext in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin but i tried to use BindingContext to set image path 
First i tried with

```
private string _imagePath;
public string ImagePath
{
    get
    {
        return _imagePath;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_imagePath != value)
        {
            _imagePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

.
 .
 .

```
ImagePath = "TriangleSide_A.png";
```

.
 .
 .

```
<Image Source="{Binding  ImagePath}" HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300"/>
```

But no luck then i tried with Auto Property

```
public string ImagePath {get;set;}
```

Thats work only with

```
public string ImagePath {get;} = "TriangleSide_A.png";
```

Comment: So it worked ? Whats the question here...

Comment: are you on code-behind or viewmodel?   you need to implement OnPropertyChanged();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I don't know how you implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface, generally, I do like this:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The RaisePropertyChanged likes your OnPropertyChanged method, with the PropertyName that has changed. If we go to our property, we now need to update it, to raise this event, every time the property is changed.

From your code, you don't add propertyname in your OnPropertyChanged, so the ImagePath can not be updated.

Please take a look the following code:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Image
            HeightRequest="300"
            Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
            WidthRequest="300" />

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="Btn1_Clicked"
            Text="change image source" />
    </StackLayout>

 public partial class Page32 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _imagePath;
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return _imagePath; }
        set
        { 
            if (_imagePath != value)
            {
                _imagePath = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ImagePath");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;      
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public Page32()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ImagePath = "a11.jpg";
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImagePath = "a12.jpg";
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If you want to use binding in mvvm mode, I do some code that you can take a look:

This is ImageOnClick model, contain some properties.

```
 public class ImageOnClick:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _imagePath;
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return _imagePath; }
        set
        {

            if (_imagePath != value)
            {
                _imagePath = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ImagePath");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now binding this model to contentpage

```
 public partial class Page32 : ContentPage
{
    private ImageOnClick imagemodel;       
    public Page32()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        imagemodel = new ImageOnClick() { ImagePath = "a11.jpg" };

        this.BindingContext = imagemodel;
    }

    private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       imagemodel.ImagePath = "a12.jpg";
    }
}
```

About mvvm binding, you can also take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: because i need it in different class

Comment: @HristoIvanov What do you mean? Can you provide more detailed info about your issue, now I am not sure what problem do you have.

Comment: I have different class named ImageOnClick and want to connect with MyMainPage

Comment: @HristoIvanov You said that you have different class that all ImageOnClick,  if you do this, I guess that you may have error message.whether you want to add ImagePath in ImageOnClick class , then want to use mvvm mode to binding contentpage?

Comment: yeah that's exactly what i've been wanting

Answer (score 0):

Your Initial code is correct, but you can set the _imagePath to Auto Property like so:

```
private string _imagePath { get; set; }
public string ImagePath
{
    get
    {
        return _imagePath;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_imagePath != value)
        {
            _imagePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The reason

```
public string ImagePath {get;set;}
```

doesn't work is because you need to have the OnPropertyChanged() in the setter.